# Run phantomjs from php

Tags: php, phantomjs

I;m trying to run phantomjs from php. To check correct path and permissions, as first I execute this commands:

```
$output = shell_exec('ls /opt/phantomjs-1.9.2-linux-x86_64/bin/ -l');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Result:

```
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 38526976 Sep  7 11:17 phantomjs
drwxrwxrwx. 2 root root     4096 Feb 10 15:44 savedpages
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      803 Jan 19 18:36 saveonepagelin.js
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     4074 Jan 19 19:00 test.js
```

But when I run:

```
$output = shell_exec('/opt/phantomjs-1.9.2-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs --version');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Output is empty :( why? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be a permission problem. Is the www-data user (or whichever user your server is called) allowed to run the program?

Do you get anything returned if you place $output in var_dump() instead?
I.e.

```
$output = shell_exec('/opt/phantomjs-1.9.2-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs --version');
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Yes this command:   $output = shell_exec('/opt/phantomjs-1.9.2-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs  2>&1');
echo $output; output is: sh: /opt/phantomjs-1.9.2-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs: Permission denied. How I can change permissions for "apache" user?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, and I try to modify the dir where I execute the phantomjs and set the mode with 777, then it worked. I guess the root cause if the owner of the php-fpm doesn't have right to write image into the dir.

my code for refer:

```
$output = passthru('phantomjs echarts-convert.js -options ' . $options . ' -outfile line.png');

echo $output;
```